Cloud Run Job causes a memory leak when writing files with Filestore mounted with NFS
Memory leak when writing files with Filestore mounted with NFS in Cloud Run Job.
I created a task that runs for over an hour in cloud run job. The resulting files are 1-10 GB in size, and the cloud run job requires a lot of memory because the file storage is in the memory area. Therefore, we prepared Filestore, mounted it with NFS and saved the files in /mnt/example. I thought I could run with less memory if I did that.
However, the memory of the cloud run job increased by the size of the file, and the result was not what I expected.
enter image description here
How can I make it run with more files but less memory?
The following is a simplified version of the actual command used
gcloud run jobs create mnt-example \
    --project example \
    --region asia-northeast1 \
    --image asia-northeast1-docker.pkg.dev/example/example-app/mnt-example:latest \
    --add-volume name=nfs,type=nfs,location=10.118.2.2:/example \
    --add-volume-mount volume=nfs,mount-path=/mnt/example \
    --cpu 1 \
    --memory 1Gi \
    --tasks 1 \
    --task-timeout 3h
gcloud run jobs execute mnt-example \
    --project example \
    --region asia-northeast1

